# Karma/Jasmine Cannot resolve module 'angular2/http'

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack, karma-jasmine

This is my first Angular2 project and the other dev who set up the build scripts is on vacation and I am having a really hard time understanding what is going on.

I am building an app that makes use of angular2/http and the http module is working as expected in the app, but not for testing. I am attempting to configure Karma/Jasmine to make some unit tests but I am receiving the following error that is preventing me from being able to write tests for any component that makes use of angular2/http.

> WARNING in ./src/app/services/auth/auth.service.spec.ts Module build
>   failed: Error: Cannot resolve module 'angular2/http' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/src/app/services/auth
>       Required in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/src/app/services/auth/auth.service.spec.ts
>       at ResolutionError.Error (native)
>       at new ResolutionError (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist.babel/deps.js:515:88)
>       at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/node_modules/awesome-typescript-loader/dist.babel/deps.js:340:37
>       at run (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:89:22)
>       at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.promise.js:102:28
>       at flush (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/node_modules/core-js/modules/_microtask.js:18:9)
>       at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)  @ ./src .spec.ts

auth-service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router-deprecated';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private loggedIn = false;
  private events = [];

  constructor(private http: Http, private router: Router){
    // TODO check for token in local storage
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }

  login(username, password, companyId){

    console.log(this.http);
    console.log('http request firing...');
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');

    return this.http
        .post(
            '/authenticate',
            JSON.stringify({ username, password, companyId }),
            {headers}
        )
        .subscribe(
            res => {
              this._login(res);
            },
            err => {
              this._login(err);
            }
        )
  }

  private _login(res){

    if(res.status === 200)  {
      this.loggedIn = true;
      this.router.navigate(['My Trips']);
      //TODO: store user information in UserService?
    }

    let resJson = res.json();

    this.triggerEvent(res.status, resJson);

  }

  logout(){
    // TODO remove token from local storage
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }

  isLoggedIn(){
    return this.loggedIn;
  }

  addEventListener(payload){

    this.events.push(payload);

  }

  removeEventListener(payload) {
   this.events.splice(this.events.indexOf(payload), 1);
  }

  triggerEvent(theEvent, payload = {}){
    this.events.forEach( (evt) =>  {
      evt(theEvent, payload);
    });
  }


}
```

auth-service.spec.ts:

```
import {
  beforeEachProviders,
  it,
  describe,
  expect,
  inject
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Http, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

describe('Auth Service', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [AuthService, Http]);

  it('should ...',
      inject([AuthService, Http], (service: AuthService, http: Http) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

spec-bundle.js:

```
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity;

require('core-js');

// Typescript emit helpers polyfill
require('ts-helpers');

require('zone.js/dist/zone');
require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
require('zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch');
require('zone.js/dist/async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/fake-async-test');
require('zone.js/dist/sync-test');

// RxJS
require('rxjs/Rx');

var testing = require('@angular/core/testing');
var browser = require('@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing');

testing.setBaseTestProviders(
  browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
  browser.TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
);

Object.assign(global, testing);


var testContext = require.context('../src', true, /\.spec\.ts/);

function requireAll(requireContext) {
  return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
}

// requires and returns all modules that match
var modules = requireAll(testContext);
```

karma-conf.js:

```
/**
 * @author: @AngularClass
 */

module.exports = function(config) {
  var testWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.js');

  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (e.g. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    /*
     * Frameworks to use
     *
     * available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
     */
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [ ],

    /*
     * list of files / patterns to load in the browser
     *
     * we are building the test environment in ./spec-bundle.js
     */
    files: [ { pattern: './spec-bundle.js', watched: false } ],

    /*
     * preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
     * available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
     */
    preprocessors: { './spec-bundle.js': ['coverage', 'webpack', 'sourcemap'] },

    // Webpack Config at ./webpack.test.js
    webpack: testWebpackConfig,

    coverageReporter: {
      dir : 'coverage/',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'json' },
        { type: 'html' }
      ]
    },

    // Webpack please don't spam the console when running in karma!
    webpackServer: { noInfo: true },

    /*
     * test results reporter to use
     *
     * possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
     * available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
     */
    reporters: [ 'mocha', 'coverage' ],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    /*
     * level of logging
     * possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
     */
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,

    /*
     * start these browsers
     * available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
     */
    browsers: [
      'Chrome',
      'Firefox',
      'PhantomJS'
    ],

    /*
     * Continuous Integration mode
     * if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
     */
    singleRun: true
  });

};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "connect-portal",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Amex GBT CONNECT Portal app, built off of the Angular 2 Webpack Starter kit",
  "scripts": {
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "typings": "typings",
    "webpack": "webpack",
    "webpack-dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "clean": "npm cache clean && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc typings coverage dist",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "preclean:start": "npm run clean",
    "clean:start": "npm start",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "prebuild:dev": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:dev": "webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "prebuild:prod": "npm run clean:dist",
    "build:prod": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached --bail & npm run copyindex",
    "copyindex": "copyfiles --up 1 static/*.html templates",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config config/webpack.dev.js --inline --progress --profile --colors --watch --display-error-details --display-cached --content-base src/",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --hot",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist --cors",
    "webdriver:update": "npm run webdriver-manager update",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "lint": "npm run tslint 'src/**/*.ts'",
    "pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update -- --standalone",
    "e2e": "npm run protractor",
    "e2e:live": "npm run e2e -- --elementExplorer",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "karma start",
    "ci": "npm test && npm run e2e",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "postinstall": "npm run typings -- install",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "copyfiles": "^0.2.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "ng2-translate": "^2.1.0",
    "normalize.css": "^4.1.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angularclass/angular2-beta-to-rc-alias": "~0.0.3",
    "angular2-hmr": "~0.7.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~0.17.0",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.19",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-promise-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.6.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.3",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.17.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "parse5": "^1.5.1",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "protractor": "^3.2.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.6.3",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^0.7.3",
    "tslint": "^3.7.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "~1.8.9",
    "typings": "~1.0.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "^0.0.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

I am fairly new to Angular, but I am sure this is an issue with dependency injection in one form or another. I have attempted to change the service to use '@angular/http' but this creates a multitude of other errors in the webpack build where scss files are no longer loaded properly.

I have attempted to find an answer to a similar problem, but have not had any success. I apologize in advance if I am making a rookie mistake, I am a rookie after all! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';` instead `angular2/http`

Comment: @yurzui I have tried that, It ends up breaking a bunch of other stuff in the build process:

`ERROR in ./src/scss/style.scss
Module parse failed: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/AMEX/connect-portal-shell/src/main/resources/src/scss/style.scss Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)` 

And then none of the other test files are loaded. With 'angular2/http' all other test .spec files load ok.

Comment: Do you set up `sass-loader` in your `webpack.test.js`?

Comment: @yurzui Yes, I tried that and it just creates more and more issues. Ideally, I would like to continue to use 'angular2/http' as the app itself is working fine using that module. The issue is in the testing configuration I believe. Are you aware of a specific place that you define dependencies for testing that is different from the regular app build?